# Setting page title through javascript

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

How do I set this page Title through javascript

```
<head runat="server">
    <link href="../App_Themes/CSS/Catalyst.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title><asp:Literal ID="ltlTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do something like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
  document.title = "This is the new page title.";

  //or 

 $(document).attr('title', 'test');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check by the following code:

```
document.title="My Title by Vaibhav";
document.write(document.title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('title').html("new title");
```